# Cannot change directory into home directory, although permissions are set correct

Tags: ubuntu, unix, permissions, chmod

I guess I need some help from an advanced Unix user...

On a Ubuntu System I did something stupid. I typed `sudo chmod 774 .*` or the like, in a subfolder of my home folder and then I suddenly could not change the directory to my home directory anymore.
I'm not quite sure about the exact numbers in the command, but I am sure about the `.*`.

Now, after a reboot, I can't even log into the GUI anymore and when I `Ctrl + Alt + F1` into a console and log in, I get the message `No directory, logging in with HOME=/`.

When I then try to `cd` into `/home/myusername`, I get the error: `-bash: cd: /home/myusername: Permission denied`. Also, `ls` can't access the folder.

I checked the permissions of `/home/myusername` using sudo, and they are all correctly set to:

`drwxr-xr-x 25 myusername myusername 4096 Aug 26 17:30 myusername`

A testuser, that I created, has the same promblems. It cannot log into the GUI, either. Only a guest session can do it (I guess that is because the guest home folder is created inside `/tmp`).

What do I need to do, to restore my permissions/get access to my home folder again??? Any suggestions?

Cheers, Sebastian

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home`? Maybe there is a `x` permission missing for a directory? `ls -ld /home`

Comment: @VolkerSiegel There was indeed an `x` permission missing for world in `/home`. Seems like this solved the problem! I will report, once I have confirmed that all is functioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you own your home direcory `/home/myusername`, and have `rwx` permissions on it.

But a
`cd /home/myusername`
 gives a `Permission denied`?

That looks like you are not allowed to look at `/home` in the to begin with, before it comes to actually looking up `myusername` in that directory.

With
  `sudo chmod 774 .*`
in `/home/myusername`, you included the file `..`.
And `/home/myusername/..` is the same as `/home`.

The permissions were applied as root, so the `4` is what applies to you a a normal user. this is `r--`, it does not contain the execute permission. On a directory, the execute permission is what allows you to look inside the directory.

The problem applies to all users that have their home directory under `/home`, as you already found out.

Comment: Right! Since the rights of home were accidentally set to `drwxrwxr-- root  root  4096 Aug 26 17:30 home`, none of the ordinary users could access it. With a `sudo chmod u+X /home` the problem could be fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: in my case `/` did not have correct permissions